# Finite ring having $2^n-1$ invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $A$ be a ring with $0\neq1$ having $2^n-1$ invertible elements and at most $2^n-1$ non-invertible elements. Then $A$ must be a field? How many elements does the ring need to have? Because $2^n-1$ is odd, the characteristic of the ring is $2$. Thank you!

Comment: One question: why must |A| be a power of two?

Comment: @DanielFischer: There is a slight gap between this Question and the duplicate cited, namely here the number of non-invertible elements is at most $2^n - 1$ and there the number of non-invertible elements is strictly less than $2^n - 1$.  However this only affects the second step of azimut's Answer there, bracketing $2^n - 1 \lt |A| \le 2(2^n - 1)$ where $|A|$ is the size of ring $A$.  The conclusion $|A| = 2^n$ remains.

Comment: @hardmath Well, yes, here we have the bounds $2^n - 1 < \lvert A\rvert \leqslant 2\cdot 2^n - 1$, I figured that doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @user265311:  The order of the additive group of $A$ is $|A|$.  If $|A|$ had an odd prime factor $p$, then by the structure theorem for finite abelian groups, there would be some element $u \neq -u$.

Comment: @user265311 Since the characteristic is $2$, it is a $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector space.